# Can SAML send assign/send the same browser id for two users who have different authentication user id's

Tags: security, single-sign-on, saml

I am not a Security Engineer, but here is the issue. Two users (A & B) live in different states. Each user log into network with assigned user id and passwords. One day a User A logged into an application and User B's profile appeared. The application is cloud-based and uses SSO. When logging into the application users have the ability to click on remember this device check box. Doing do, upon subsequent logins, the application will simple open to the default home screen. The Vendor support team advised that this is an issue with SSO. They believe that somehow the two users have the same browser id, which SAML used to send to the application for authentication. Has anyone encountered an issue similar to the one I described? If so,what is the fix? I will do my best to answer you questions as best as I can. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Without any indication of platform involved it's impossible to provide any reasonable answer as to what happened. Is it feasible a bug exists in the SAML IdP that confused one identity for another? Of course. Bugs happen all the time. Security is hard.

Comment: Steve, ok, thanks for the response. i hope this post does not get closed. I would like to provide the information that makes the post clear. I will get additional information